# Next.js - Suppress specific warning in dev mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

currently migrating a CRA app to Next.js for better SEO.

I'm getting the following warning in development mode: `Warning: 'NaN' is an invalid value for the 'left' css style property`.

I know what's causing the warning: a `left: 100%;` CSS style tag buried deep within a PrimeReact component (which it would be a headache to change).
Is there a way to suppress this specific warning?

Or, alternatively, if you believe there's an easy fix, happy to hear it, though since I understand what's causing the issue I'm happy to just suppress the warning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't figured out how to suppress the warning, this is no longer relevant. I filed this as an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/5111) with the PrimeReact team, who promptly fixed it - thanks!